# What's the most reliable way to get the start and end positions of current symbol under cursor?

Tags: region, symbols, thing-at-point

What's the most reliable way to get the start and end positions of the symbol at the cursor location (point)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `thingatpt.el` API works as follows:

```
(thing-at-point 'symbol) ;=> foo
(beginning-of-thing 'symbol) ;=> 42
(end-of-thing 'symbol) ;=> 45
(bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol) ;=> (42 . 45)
```

While it's not 100% reliable as it relies on `(forward-thing 'symbol)` to do the right thing, it's pretty good and one of the better APIs in Emacs.  Give it a try!

Comment: Note that, unless someone takes steps to make it do otherwise, `(forward-thing 'symbol)` calls `forward-symbol` which certainly does the right thing in terms of the buffer's syntax table and the syntax-based definition of "symbol".

Answer (score 1):

I would expect `symbol-at-point` to be reliable.

Given that you yourself tagged this question with `thing-at-point`, are you asking in particular whether there are flaws with this method?

Comment: `symbol-at-point` or `thing-at-point` returns current symbol at point, but I'd like to get the start/end `point`(the exact boundary) of this symbol...

Comment: Oh yes. I ought to have said `(bounds-of-thing-at-point 'symbol)`. But the same question applies -- you *seem* to already be aware of `thing-at-point` (and hence the `thingatpt.el` library in general), so are you specifically questioning its reliability, or was it simply that you hadn't noticed the function in question?

Comment: I hadn't noticed the function, though I use `thing-at-point` quite often ...And as @wasamasa pointed out, the function may not be 100% reliable, though I've not encountered such situations. Thanks for you information.

Comment: I've run into it being unreliable with Evil and other modes doing weird things, see https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/844 for example.

Comment: That particular instance sounds like an issue with the evil library's thing-at-point handler(s) for `evil-defun` rather than `symbol`, though? I would expect the handling of `symbol` to be reliable. For the standard "things" I would expect this to be as reliable as other methods for obtaining the same information (but certainly there may be bugs for more complex "things" where the behaviour may be down to individual modes to define).